# Storing with CoreData

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

my app is very simple: I have one tableview to store recipe *names and, for each recipe name, another tableview with several *ingredients for each recipe.

I already managed to save the name and the ingredients with CoreData, but here is the problem: when I press to add a NEW recipe name and enter the ingredients table view area, the ingredients saved for the previous recipe are there! How do I clear the table view to start a new one?

Also, my table views does not get updated immediately, I have to close the app and open it again. How do I fix it?

Note: If my question is too hard to understand, I can post some code! Thanks in advance, everyone =)

**EDIT**

code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var imageList: [UIImage] = []
    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchName(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fetchName() -> NSFetchRequest {
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Details")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recipeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if let recipeCell = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Details {
            cell.textLabel?.text = recipeCell.name
        }
        return cell 
    }
}
```

-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class InfoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Pick the image by tap
        let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "chooseImage:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    //Pick the image by tapping, accessing the photoLibrary
    func chooseImage(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //Put the selected image into the screen
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject:AnyObject]) {
        let pickedImage: UIImage = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
        // small picture
        let smallPicture = scaleImageWith(pickedImage, newSize: CGSizeMake(288,148))
        var sizeOfImageView:CGRect = imageView.frame
        sizeOfImageView.size = smallPicture.size
        imageView.frame = sizeOfImageView
        imageView.image = smallPicture
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func scaleImageWith(image:UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Details", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let details = Details(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        details.name = nameField.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Ingredient \(nameField.text) saved successfully!")
        }
            if let navigation = navigationController {
            navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }
    }
}
```

-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class IngredientListViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchIngredient(), managedObjectContext: moc!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fetchIngredient() -> NSFetchRequest {
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Ingredients")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ingredients", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.predicate = nil
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        return fetchRequest
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section].numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        if let recipeCell = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Ingredients {
            cell.textLabel?.text = recipeCell.ingredients
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

-

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class IngredientViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Ingredients", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let details = Ingredients(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        details.ingredients = nameField.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Ingredient \(nameField.text) saved successfully!")
        }
        if let navigation = navigationController {
            navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

        }
    }
}
```

and models:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Ingredients: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var ingredients: String
    @NSManaged var relationship: NSSet
```

### }

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Details: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var relationship: Ingredients

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In outline:

1. You need to amend your model: currently each `Details` object can have only one `Ingredients`.  I suspect you need this relationship to be "to many" so a recipe can have many ingredients.
2. You need to add a var (of type `Details?`) to your `IngredientListViewController`.  This will represent the chosen Recipe.  (eg. `var chosenRecipe : Details?`)
3. In `fetchIngredient`, you need to add a predicate to the fetch, to limit the results to the chosen recipe.  eg. `fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"ANY relationship == %@", chosenRecipe)`
4. Before segueing to this VC, you need to set the `chosenRecipe` (probably in prepareForSegue, or didSelectRowAtIndexPath in the preceding table view).
5. To get your TV to update automatically, use the `fetchedResultsController` delegate methods.  (Have you implemented these?)

Comment: I managed to make my tableviews work, but I still don't know how to clear the list for when I add a new item, the old ones won't show. I'll let you know when I'm done!

Comment: I don't know how to set CoreData to clear all the data when I start a new item :( Could you teach me?

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli Can you explain the residual problem a little more?

Comment: Imagine this: I have a tableview with several items, and each item will have its own tableview with its own items. For example. when I add the first recipe and add its ingredients it's everything ok, but when I enter a second recipe, and try to add its new ingredients, the ingredients for the preview recipe are there! And so on. They accumulate. I wish to learn how to clear the ingredients tableview each time I add a new recipe.

Comment: Note: I must reset it but keep it in memory, because later when I access the row for each recipe added, via didSelecRowAtIndexPath, a screen will be shown with the details for each recipe.

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli OK.  My intention was that the predicate would filter out the ingredients so only those for the current recipe were shown.  But I'm about to go to bed - I'll think on it overnight.

Comment: I tried something like when I add a new ingredient, I would only unwind the view, then, in viewDidLoad I would do something like tableView.clearAllData, but I didn't find anything in apple docs that could satisfy what I want to do.  Is it actually possible?

Comment: Did you get anything? I tried to check if the "next screen" is a new screen, if negative, it would show the old ingredients, if positive, it would tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad, but it doesn't seem to work. I guess I have to figure out another to make my app work.

Comment: Sorry, I've been tied up today; I should have some time tomorrow.  I haven't fully understood the VCs and the segues between them.  But if you are unwinding or popping, the previous VC's `viewDidLoad` will not be called.  Try `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli Have you had any success?  If you explain your VCs/segues a little more, I'm sure we can crack it.

Comment: The ViewController goes to InfoViewcontroller via navigation bar button, in InfoViewcontroller there is another navigation bar button that goes to IngredientsListViewController, which has a tableView. This last one has another navigation bar button thar goes to a screen (IngredientsViewController), that has a textField and a button, where I insert the ingredient that will be shown in the previous tableView . This tableView is the problem, because if I try to add another recipe, the old ingredients are still there.

Comment: I haven't had any success, but I did not try with viewWillAppear

Comment: I'm thinking another way for its logics, maybe we add a 'Reset ingredients' button to clear the entire list. What do you think?

Comment: That should not be necessary.  So, to check, IngredientsListViewController is the problematic one?  And in which VC do you add new Recipes?

Comment: The first VC will store the recipe names. Later, I'll set one last VC that will show name, photo and the ingredients. That's why I need to keep all that info in memory. But it's really cool to wipe everything from the ingredients list tableView everytime you add a new recipe

Comment: I've set up a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85037/room-for-pbasdf-and-nicholas-piccoli) if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: I've read your answer on the chat room! I'll give it a try tomorrow morning and let you know if it worked. I'm currently on iPhone that's why I can't answer you there. Tomorrow morning I'll tell you if it worked, I liked your idea! Thanks for all the help. Really.